# Order of constructor and destructor calling?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I cannot understand the order of constructor and destructor calls? What will execute first in this statement A b=f(a)? Can someone please help me out?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int x;

    public:
        A(int val = 0)
        :x(val) {
            cout << "A " << x << endl << flush;
        }
        A(const A& a) {
            x = a.x;
            cout << "B " << x << endl << flush;
        }
        void SetX(int x) {
            this->x = x;
        }
        ~A() {
            cout << "D " << x << endl << flush;
        }
};

A f(A a) {
    cout << " C " << endl << flush;
    a.SetX(100);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A a(1);
    A b=f(a);
    b.SetX(-100);
    return 0;
}
```

Output Window:

```
A 1
B 1
 C
B 100
D 100
D -100
D 1
```

Why does it print B 1 in line 2 of the output window?

Comment: The order is base classes in the order of declared inheritance, members in the order of declarations. In other words: the order in the constructor initializer list has no effect (Virtual inheritance is special).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you get `B 1` because you passed an object of type `A` to `f` by value (so it had to create copy and which lead to calling the copy ctor)

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm not sure why you're talking about inheritance here, there is only one class...

Comment: @Borgleader for completeness' sake I suppose

Comment: @DieterLücking Yeah so? That could very well refer to multiple objects in a scope, it does by no means refer specifically to inheritance so I'm curious as to why you brought it up.

Comment: @Moiz If you're tagging this as [tag:c++-faq] you obviously realize it's fequently asked. Why don't you close it as a duplicate too? See the side bar for candidates: http://i.imgur.com/DadFylj.png

Answer (score 5):

> *"Why does it print B 1 in line 2?"*

Because the copy constructor was called from this statement

```
A b=f(a);
```

The function `f()` requires `A` being passed by value, thus a copy for this parameter is made on the function call stack.

---

If your next question should be, how you can get over this behavior, and avoid to call the copy constructor, you can simply pass the `A` instance as a reference to `f()`:

```
    A& f(A& a) {
  // ^    ^
        cout << " C " << endl << flush;
        a.SetX(100);
        return a;
    }
```

---

<sub>Side note: `endl << flush;` is redundant BTW, `std::endl` includes flushing already.</sub>